# after insert the id , how to load the other values using ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax

I have a table called materials.it contains material id, name, cost_per_unit and etc.then i have form to get total cost. i want to select material id or name and then load the cost per unit for the selected item aotomatically. any one can please help me

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: no i have no idea how to do that

Comment: Hello ashik, at Stackoverflow we love to help solve programming problems, but I'm afraid none of us are willing to do your work for you.  If you have a specific question about some code  you can't getting working we would be happy to help.